# Is it possible to embed a ttinclude file in an assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, t4

Using T4 Templates, it's possible to include other files, usually with the extension ttinclude.

Is it possible to embed a ttinclude file as part of an assembly and refer to it in a normal T4 template?

Comment: Is your intention in using the same ttinclude file as a source file in library project and as template in another project? I tried to do it but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possibly to embed T4 files as resources I am unsure what gain you will get from it. The default T4 engine can't read them and licensing prevents you from distributing the T4 engine anyway.

However, if you like to have a set of T4 to reuse across other projects that's certainly possible but you don't have to embed them in assemblies.

The easiest way is just rely on your source control system. Another way is deploying them using nuget (such as T4Include for example: http://www.nuget.org/packages/T4Include).

PS. The licensing of T4 means it's intended for VS developers only.